Copy/paste skipping some columns identified with variables
I have a macro designed to copy data from Workbook1-Sheet1 and paste it into Workbook2-Sheet1.
It utilizes variables and the .Copy functions for some of the variables. It is skipping other variables. They are all written the same as the ones that work.
I repurposed essentially all of the code I used for a previous sheet doing the same thing but adding new ranges as there are more columns.
Unfortunately, the destination columns of the Target workbook are not the same as the Source workbook, and as such I cannot choose the entire workbook and copy/paste it that way. To tackle this issue, I identified the source and target ranges and applied those to variables for future reference.
The copy/paste macro is skipping variables at intermittent points. The variables are all named appropriately, pointing to the proper ranges, and the code isn't erroring out.
I've 22 total variables; 11 Source Range variables and 11 Target Range variables. The function copy/pastes the first four and the 10th variable, skipping 5-9 and the 11th reliably. Sometimes, if I run the macro a second time, it will copy/paste just the 5th and 6th variables but skip the rest. No further re-runs of the macro will populate the rest of the columns, and as soon as I launch a new instance of the target workbook, it continues to skip the same variables.
My entire code block, I put asterisks on the parts that don't seem to run:
Sub DataCopy()
'
'DataTemplate Macro
'Will copy/paste the data from the Data file into the appropriate columns.
'
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'

On Error Resume Next 'Will ignore the error this will throw in the event that there aren't any empty rows.
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete 'This will delete any rows upon finding blank cells; dangerous to use for most other sheets.
On Error GoTo 0 'Will close the "On Error Resume Next" call, and will allow errors for the rest of the codeblock.

'The above snippet is retained primarily in the event of an errant empty row being included.

    Sheets(1).Select 'Selects the first sheet in numerical order.
    Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1" 'Renames the first sheet to "Sheet1".

'    Range("A2").Select 'This will select the A2 Cell.
'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'This then sets the selection range to extend to the last cell within A2 that houses data.
'    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
'        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
'        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
'       :=Array(1, 3), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True 'This block sets different options on a date column from the "Text To Columns" Ribbon option.
'    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" 'Sets the cell range to format as Date instead of the numbers that the above block changes it to.

'We don't need the above code block because the dates are usually sent in the right format, but we're keeping it to implement later if necessary.

'
Dim Target As Worksheet 'Defines "Target" as a worksheet.
Dim rngm1, rngm2, rngm3, rngm4, rngm5, rngm6, rngm7, rngm8, rngm9, rngm10, rngm11 As Range 'Defines the "main" ranges as ranges.
Dim rngt1, rngt2, rngt3, rngt4, rngt5, rngt6, rngt7, rngt8, rngt9, rngt10, rngt11 As Range 'Defines the "target" ranges as ranges.
Dim lastrow As Object 'Defines "lastrow" as an Object explicitly.
Dim tsitea As Range
Dim tsiteb As Range
Dim i As Integer 'Setting this as an Integer assigns it to a 32bit limit, which is fine for what this variable is used for.
Dim m As Long 'Both m and k need to be "Long", which are larger bit limits -- this is necessary because the row sizes are much much higher.
Dim k As Long
'
'
'
Set Target = Workbooks("DataTarget.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1") 'This sets the "Target" variable to a specific workbook + identifies the sheets.
'
Set lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Rows

i = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
'MsgBox "This is the last row " & i 'This is to troubleshoot and to confirm the amount of rows within the sheet.

Set rngm1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) '"ActiveWorkbook" specifies the workbook you have open at the time of running.
Set rngm2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)) 'This is true for the remainder of rngm1-11.
Set rngm3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm4 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)) '.Range("x", Range("x").End(xlDown)) will select to when data ends in that column.
Set rngm5 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm6 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm7 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm8 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm9 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I2", Range("I2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm10 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown))
Set rngm11 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K2", Range("K2").End(xlDown))

Set rngt1 = Target.Range("A2") 'Adding this before the offset variables below will make this macro work for blank books.
Set rngt2 = Target.Range("H2")
Set rngt3 = Target.Range("G2")
Set rngt4 = Target.Range("B2")
Set rngt5 = Target.Range("J2")
Set rngt6 = Target.Range("K2")
Set rngt7 = Target.Range("L2")
Set rngt8 = Target.Range("I2")
Set rngt9 = Target.Range("O2")
Set rngt10 = Target.Range("Q2")
Set rngt11 = Target.Range("N2")

On Error Resume Next
Set rngt1 = Target.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) '"Target" is already specified in the above variable, so all I have to do is define the range I want.
Set rngt2 = Target.Range("H2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'As above, this continues further through rngt1-11.
Set rngt3 = Target.Range("G2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngt4 = Target.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'There is no need to declare the full range, only the target/destination cells and columns.
Set rngt5 = Target.Range("J2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) 'Setting the range to the end of the column with a Row offset of 1 will paste the data directly beneath already existing data.
Set rngt6 = Target.Range("K2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngt7 = Target.Range("L2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngt8 = Target.Range("I2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngt9 = Target.Range("O2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngt10 = Target.Range("Q2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngt11 = Target.Range("N2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
On Error GoTo 0

rngm1.Copy rngt1 'Assigning the ".Copy" at the end of rngm% and then following it with rngt% can be read as:
rngm2.Copy rngt2 '"Copy from rngm% Paste to rngt%.
rngm3.Copy rngt3
rngm4.Copy rngt4
**rngm5.Copy rngt5** <--
**rngm6.Copy rngt6** <--
**rngm7.Copy rngt7** <--
**rngm8.Copy rngt8** <--
**rngm9.Copy rngt9** <--
rngm10.Copy rngt10
**rngm11.Copy rngt11** <--

k = Target.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row 'This is getting the total amount of rows in the sheet.
MsgBox "The amount of rows in Target Sheet B are " & k 'These MsgBox lines are more for QA and to confirm the amount of rows.
m = Target.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row '
MsgBox "The amount of rows in Target Sheet A are " & m 'If they slow the process down significantly, then they can be commented out.

If m < k Then 'This statement takes the row counts from above and runs the codeblock underneath if m is less than k.
    Set tsitea = Target.Range("E" & m) 'This changes the source copy to be the final row found by m.
    Set tsiteb = Target.Range("E" & m, "E" & k) 'Sets tsiteb to be from the last row found by m to the last row found by k.

    tsitea.Copy tsiteb 'Copies tsitea to tsiteb under the parameters set above.
End If 'Closes the If statement.

Set Target = Nothing 'Setting all of these variables as Nothing is good practice to clear memory and resources up in larger functions.
Set lastrow = Nothing
Set rngm1 = Nothing
Set rngm2 = Nothing
Set rngm3 = Nothing
Set rngm4 = Nothing
Set rngm5 = Nothing
Set rngm6 = Nothing
Set rngm7 = Nothing
Set rngm8 = Nothing
Set rngm9 = Nothing
Set rngm10 = Nothing
Set rngm11 = Nothing
Set rngt1 = Nothing
Set rngt2 = Nothing
Set rngt3 = Nothing
Set rngt4 = Nothing
Set rngt5 = Nothing
Set rngt6 = Nothing
Set rngt7 = Nothing
Set rngt8 = Nothing
Set rngt9 = Nothing
Set rngt10 = Nothing
Set rngt11 = Nothing
Set tsitea = Nothing
Set tsiteb = Nothing

Application.CutCopyMode = False 'This clears the clipboard so as to prevent us from accidentally pasting a huge block of text elsewhere.

End Sub

The entire macro functions on a blank book.
On the already populated (and correct) workbook, it does not simply overwrite data at the top of the sheet.

Are those target variable ranges getting set? I would start by removing ON Error Resume Next and dealing with the errors that pop instead of ignoring.

FYI I think it's typically accepted there's no need to set object-type variables to Nothing at the end of a Sub/Function.

Also Dim rngm1, rngm2, rngm3, rngm4, rngm5, rngm6, rngm7, rngm8, rngm9, rngm10, rngm11 As Range only declares rngm1 as Range  - all others on that line will be Variant

Possibly useful: How to find the last used cell.

In response to JNevill:  I believe the variables are actually being set, as when I mouse over the copy function, it identifies the data appropriately, which leads me to believe that it's seeing the ranges that the variables are referencing.

In response to Tim Williams:  I did not know that it would make the others as Variant!  I went ahead and gave them all As Range specifiers.  The issue is still persisting, unfortunately.

If this is a table of data you're transferring, then treating each column as if it has an independent number of rows is a problem, since it can end up with your pasted columns getting mis-aligned.

You really don't need most of those variables. Here's a more compact approach:
Sub DataCopy()
    
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, lrSrc As Long, lrTarget As Long
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet 'Defines "Target" as a worksheet.
    Dim arrSrcCols, arrDestCols, col
    Dim i As Long 'No real saving in using Integer...
    
    Set wbSrc = ActiveWorkbook 'define which workbook is being copied from
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
    
    'in case any empty cells in Col A are included....
    On Error Resume Next 'only really needed if ColA is completely filled
    wsSrc.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set wsTarget = Workbooks("DataTarget.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'last row to copy and paste row should be the same for all columns...
    lrSrc = LastOccupiedRow(wsSrc)
    lrTarget = LastOccupiedRow(wsTarget)
    
    'zero-based arrays of source + destination columns for each range being copied
    arrSrcCols = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K")
    arrDestCols = Array("A", "H", "G", "B", "J", "K", "L", "I", "O", "Q", "N")
    
    For i = LBound(arrSrcCols) To UBound(arrSrcCols)
        'range to copy
        Set rng = wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Cells(2, arrSrcCols(i)), _
                              wsSrc.Cells(lrSrc, arrSrcCols(i)))
        'perform copy
        rng.Copy Target.Cells(lrTarget + 1, arrDestCols(i))
    Next i
    
    'rest of your code here
    
End Sub

'return the last occupied row on a worksheet
Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function


While I had to declare rng and create an rngt object to avoid invalid qualifier errors, this corrected my issue!  It is no longer skipping columns, and it's much more compact than what I had prior so that's a bonus!  I appreciate it!
